# Proving a statement from two basic ones using the logical equivalences

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Take as a known fact that, for any sets A and B,

```
      A ⊆ B if and only if A ∩ B = A:
```

Let X, Y , and Z be sets
 and

```
      X ⊂ Z and Y ⊂ Z:
```

(a) Using only this fact and Fundamental Laws of Boolean Algebra, show that

```
      X ∪ Y ⊆ Z:
```

---

My attempt:

1. I took X ⊂ Z and Y ⊂ Z and change it to X ∩ Z and Y ∩ Z,
2. since  A ⊆ B if and only if A ∩ B.
3. After that I changed the word "and" to ∩ so it becomes: X ∩ Z ∩ Y ∩ Z.
4. From the last statement I can deduce that: X ∩ Y ∩ Z.
5. Then split it to two parts 1) X ∩ (Y ∩ Z) and 2) Y ∩ (X ∩ Z).
6. Yielding X ∩ Y ⊆ Z, and Y ∩ X ⊆ Z.
7. Which can be summarized in one statement (Y ∪ X) ⊆ Z.

The part that I messed up is the last part where I used Union without any valid justification.

Comment: Well, one "part that you messed up" consistently is omitting the $ = ___$ part of every statement in 1. through 5. For example, you "took $X\subset Z$ and change it to $X\cap Z$" -- you mean $X\cap Z = Z$", etc.

Answer (score 1):

We have $X\cap Z=X, Y\cap Z=Y$, so by distributive law we have
$$(X\cup Y)\cap Z=(X\cap Z)\cup (Y\cap Z)=X\cup Y,$$ which shows $X\cup Y\subseteq Z$.

Comment: Why did you use the distributive law? Did you combine the two statements and added the union?

Comment: Why shouldn't I use distributive property, isn't it a  ''Fundamental Law of Boolean Algebra''? Sorry, I don't understand your second question...